# How to communicate between two computers in python

Tags: python, sockets

I am attempting to make a python a "buzzer" application which will function like the buzzers in jeopardy. It will (hopefully) work by linking several computers to a main computer. When a user taps the screen of their computer, if they are the first, it will change the color of their screen and alert the main computer. Now for my question: when module would be best to like together these two computer. I would need to send the name of the computer and a timestamp and the main computer would need to respond. I was reading that something like *socket* might work, but i am unsure. Also, could you please give me a link to documentation on whatever module you suggest. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO! While SO is for helping those need, it requires some conformity to help you with ease. Please have a read and post your issue here. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. We would be happy to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned `socket` in your question.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html

This might be appropriate for your needs, however with multiple clients it can get quite complicated.

Also, you may want to try using email for easier connections (if you don't mind the send time of a few seconds). I know it sounds stupid, but it has worked for me in the past, with significantly less difficulty than a multi-threaded socket connection.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.html

https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html

Comment: Email probably isn't an ideal solution in this case, due to the time sensitive nature of a 'buzzer' program.

Comment: I chose to use sockets, and now the functionality of my program works perfectly. (I still need to work on the front end).

Comment: Eventually, I ended up using pyBluez so it could work independently of WiFi.